# trying to set text of a named cell

Tags: excel

I am using vbscript (.vbs file) to set the values of an excel sheet.

I can set the cell value as follows, `objExcel.Cells(10, 10).Value = "someText"` but if the cell has a name "`myCell`" is it possible to set this directly without knowing the cells actual location?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
objExcel.Range("CustomName").Value = "someText"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("myCell").RefersToRange.Value = "someText"
```